# Java wrapping a collection

Tags: java, collections

I need to wrap five classes: `linkedlist`, `treeset`, `hashset`, and two classes I created myself.

The wrapper and my two classes are all implementing the same interface.
this is the wrapper constructor:

```
private Collection <String> collection;     
public CollectionFacadeSet(java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> collection){  
        this.collection = collection;
    }
```

now, in another class I want to create a 5 cell array that each cell houses a different set.

This line is OK:

```
static CollectionFacadeSet[] setArray = new CollectionFacadeSet[5];
```

BUT, when I create a method that fills the cells:

```
    private static void initializieArray(){
    setArray[0] = CollectionFacadeSet(HashSet<String>);
}
```

it throws me an error:

> Syntax error on token ">", Expression expected after this token

How to initiate each cell with a different set type?

Answer (score 6):

The expression

```
setArray[0] = CollectionFacadeSet(HashSet<String>);
```

is invalid. You would need something like

```
setArray[0] = new CollectionFacadeSet(new HashSet<String>());
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
static CollectionFacadeSet[] setArray = new CollectionFacadeSet[5];
```

Array will store the objects of CollectionFacadeSet so use `new`

```
setArray[0] = new CollectionFacadeSet(new HashSet<String>());
```